# SwiftUi how can I align an overlay to the top left corner of a videos with different heights

Tags: swiftui, geometry

I have a video player that has videos of different heights . I have an overlay that I am using but the issue is I can not get the overlay to show up in the top left corner of a video . Since video height is dynamic I am trying to use the geometry reader to find the position of the video but it is not working, any suggestions would be great

**This is the overlay**

```
struct VideoOverlayView: View {
    var xOffset: CGFloat
    var yOffset: CGFloat

    var body: some View {
        Image(systemName: "calendar.badge.clock")
            .padding(10)
            .background(Color.white.opacity(0.7))
            .cornerRadius(8)
            .position(x: xOffset, y: yOffset)
    }
}
```

and the main view, I put in comments where the height position of the offset is controlled . Some of my videos start at the very top of the view and others start at the center of the view . If I could get the position then I can fix the issue

```
struct EditorView: View {
    @Binding var selectedVideoURL: URL?
    @State private var player: AVPlayer?
    @Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss
    @State private var isMuted = false
    @State var volume: Float = 0
    @State var VideoDate = ""
    @State private var showToast = false
    @State var postMessage = ""
    @State private var videoPlayerY: CGFloat = 0
    
    
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            VStack {
                HStack{
                    Image(systemName: "arrowshape.turn.up.backward.fill")
                        .onTapGesture {
                            dismiss()
                        }
                    Spacer()
                    Text(VideoDate)
                        .bold()
                    Spacer()
                }.padding([.leading,.trailing],15)
                    .padding(.bottom,5)
                
                if let _ = selectedVideoURL {
                    
                    ZStack(alignment: .topLeading) {
                        Color.black.ignoresSafeArea(.all)
                        VStack {

                            VStack {
                                VideoPlayer(player: player)
                                    .background(Color.black)
                                    .frame(width: geometry.size.width, height: geometry.size.height)
                                    .overlay(
                                        GeometryReader { videoGeometry in
                                            VideoOverlayView(
                                                xOffset: 20 + 10,
                                                yOffset: geometry.size.height - videoGeometry.size.height // Here is where overlay position is controlled
                                            )
                                        },
                                        alignment: .topLeading
                                    )
                            }
                            
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Instead of trying to do the offset, you can probably just give the overlay a frame with an alignment : `.frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .topLeading)` and get rid of all of the `GeometryReader` code

Comment: Get rid of GeometryReader and use `.overlay(alignment: .topLeading) { content }`